# MS SQL Server Express CPU

Tags: sql-server

The specs say "limited to the lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores" however if you have two express instances on the same server and that server has 8 cores CPU 0-7, is it possible to assign instance 1 to CPU 0-3 and instance 2 to CPU 4-7?

Comment: **[`Affinity Mask `](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186255%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

Comment: Let me clarify, yes I know you can set this up using Affinity Mask, however the actual question is does Express override this so ONLY CPU 0-3 are used OR will it actually use CPU 4-7.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Express Edition will honor the specified processor affinity settings but not more than the 4 core edition limitation.  I don't think it's defined which 4 cores are used if you specify more than 4.  Note that unlike other SQL Server editions, a service restart is required for changes to take affect.